# Setting input Value in useState in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I am trying to set some values of inputs through `useState()` hook below in the code through `onChange` event and want to get the author id in authorId. But when I `console.log()` the newObj after putting the values, every other var is set but the auhtorId is returned as it's initial state which is empty string. Can the you tell me what I am doing wrong ?

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/client';
import {AuthorsQuery }from '../queries/Queries'


 export const AddBook = () => {



const [name, setName]= useState('');
const [genre, setGenre]= useState('');
const [authorId, setauthorId]= useState('');





const  logSubmit = (event)=>{
   
    event.preventDefault();
    const newObj = {name,genre,authorId}
    console.log(newObj)
  }

 

const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(AuthorsQuery);

if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
 if (error) return <p>Error :(</p>;

 console.log(data);






 

  return (
    
    <form id="add-book" onSubmit={logSubmit}>
    <div className="field">
        <label>Book name:</label>
        <input type="text" value={name} onChange={(e)=> setName( e.target.value)} />
    </div>
    <div className="field">
        <label>Genre:</label>
        <input type="text" value={genre} onChange={(e)=> setGenre(e.target.value)} />
    </div>
    <div className="field">
        <label>Author:</label>
                  <select onChange={(e)=>setauthorId(e.target.key)} value= 
    {author.id } >
             <option disabled>Select Author</option>
             
                 {data.authors.map(author =>(
                      <option  key={author.id}  >{author.name} </option>
                     
                 ) )
                
  }
         
       
           
            
        </select> 
        

    </div>
    <button >+</button>

  </form>
  )
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

change setauthorId by setAuthorId (for useState and onChange)

Comment: I think it is just a convention mistake and nothing todo with the problem describes although I did what you said but to no avail.

Comment: Yes, of course, you can change :e.target.key by e.target.value in your select field.

Comment: Yes I did that also but this time it gives that the author is not defined because the mapping is in the option and I am applying onChange in select box.